# Blender Cell fracture wireframe is creating separate sections rather than one form

Tags: mesh

I am fairly new to blender.

I'm trying to create a 3D voronoi structure based on a cell fracture.

My process is:

- create the mesh exterior form
- apply cell fracture
- remove the original mesh (hide)
- select all the fractured cells
- join the fractures with CTRL + J
- apply wireframe modifier (even deselected)
- apply subdivision modifier to smooth it out

When I do this it appears as though the wireframe has worked as separate sections.

[image: voronoi mesh overview]

[image: close up view showing overlapping sections]

I have tried using the merge by distance feature to remove duplicated vertices, but it doesn't seem to help.

Does anyone know how to get this into a single clean structure?

Comment: Just wondering if anyone had any feedback about this? I am thinking that I might look at Sverchok to see if that may be the end goal, but it looks as though there is a steep learning curve to understand how to create geometry with the nodes. I looked closer at the cell fracture and yes the gaps are created between the 'fractured pieces' I am unsure how to edit the setting on merge by distance to allow large variances to be captured. I found a work around by scaling the model down, then applying merge by distance, but it didn't really capture all the gaps. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I found the issue I was having. I had not known the merge by distance modal was expandable. I clicked on it and now it has the slider to adjust the distance.